# Debugger Exception Error and memory overshoot

Tags: delphi

I tried to run the following code but it shows an error regarding memory address and shows a message that 'n maybe undefined after the loop'. Please have a look.

```
var n_max : integer;
  n: integer;
  r, R1, f, h0 : Array of Real;
const
  h = 0.00889; nip= 100;
  cod = 10;
  rod = 76;
  nip_dia = 5; viscosity = 0.001; velocity = 76;
begin
  n_max := Round(((rod-cod)/2)/h);
   for n := 0 to n_max-1 do;
    r[n]:= cod/2 + h*n;
    R1[n] := (r[n]*(nip_dia)/2)/(r[n]+(nip_dia)/2);
    f[n] := nip*((r[n]-r[0])/r[n]);
    h0[n] :=4*viscosity*velocity*(1/(60*(R1[n]/f[n])));


WriteLn(r[n]);
WriteLn(R1[n]);
WriteLn(f[n]);
WriteLn(h0[n]);

ReadLn;
end.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't allocate any memory for the arrays. You need to call to `SetLength` to do that.

```
SetLength(r, n_max);
// and likewise for the other arrays
```

What's more, the loop does nothing. The loop contains a single statement which is an empty statement terminated by the semi-colon after the `do`.

```
for n := 0 to n_max-1 do;
// yes, that semi-colon is the end of the loop
```

You'll need a `begin`/`end` block.

```
for n := 0 to n_max-1 do
begin
  // loop body goes in here
  ....
end;
// at this point, outside the loop, the value of n is ill-defined.
```

Comment: Yeah it works and I am able to compile the code but even if I try to put the WriteLn statements in the for loop and try to print the output I don't get the complete array and it's showing some ridiculous value like:
for r[n] it's 3.79996800000000E+0001

Comment: @stin_crane You can use the [Format](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/XE6/en/System.SysUtils.Format) command to output the result in better format.

Comment: @David It's showing that there is no overloaded version of format command that can be used with these sort of arguments

Comment: As you are using `WriteLn` http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/VCL/2010/en/System.Write, you can use the "old-fashioned" Pascal formatting using :Digits:Decimals, e.g. `WriteLn(r[n]:10:5)` to display as `3.79997`, or `WriteLn(r[n]:5:1)` to display as `3.8`

Comment: That's a different issue unrelated to your question which I think is answered

Comment: @David yeah it has been answered. But still when I run the code in VCL form with a TButton and assign the value r[0] to TEdit1, I still get 0.000, I think the value of r[n] is not changing and system is showing the default value. I can't understand why

Comment: That's a different question. Feel free to ask another question. If this one has been answered then you might consider accepting the answer.

Comment: @David yeah it has been answered. Thanks!