# No change in array value

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe

I tried to check for the initial elements of the four arrays but the system is throwing a default value which is .000. It looks like the loop is running but still the value of all the elements is not changing. Please have a look!

```
var
  Form1: TForm1;
  n_max : integer;
  n: integer;
  r, R1, f, h0 : Array of Real;

const
  h = 0.00889; nip= 100;
  cod = 10;
  rod = 76;
  nip_dia = 5; viscosity = 0.001; velocity = 76;


implementation

{$R *.dfm}


    procedure TForm1.Button1Click(Sender: TObject);
    begin

       n_max := Round(((rod-cod)/2)/h);
       Setlength(r, n_max);
       Setlength(f, n_max);
       Setlength(h0, n_max);
       Setlength(R1, n_max);

       for n := 0 to n_max-1 do;

        r[n]:= cod/2 + h*n;
        R1[n] := (r[n]*(nip_dia)/2)/(r[n]+(nip_dia)/2);
        f[n] := nip*((r[n]-r[0])/r[n]);
        h0[n] :=4*viscosity*velocity*(1/(60*(R1[n]/f[n])));


       Edit1.Text := FormatFloat('#.00', r[1]);
       Edit2.Text := FormatFloat('#.00', f[1]);
       Edit3.Text := FormatFloat('#.00', h0[1]);
       Edit4.Text := FormatFloat('#.00', R1[1]);


    end;

    end.
```

Comment: There's nothing in the body of your for loop.

Comment: The loop is stopped at `do;`. It should start a begin end block.

Comment: I tried the begin end but still it's throwing the same .00 value

Comment: Are you sure you didn't misplace a ; when you tried begin end?

Comment: You made the same mistake at your last question. This was explained to you. Please re-read the answer to your last question.

Comment: David already pointed out this problem in his [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/24130138/224704) to your previous question.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan, I feel like there has to be a better, more general question to make this a duplicate of and if not, the original could maybe rewritten to be more general. Thoughts?

Comment: @overactor I don't think there's much value for future visitors. The main point of the dupe close here is to make it very clear to asker that he should take more care reading the answers to questions. What's the point in asking if you don't read the answer?

Comment: @all apologies, next time I'll try to contemplate the answer. This is my first time on this site and I am a beginner in coding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is not running.
It is terminated by `do;`.
You need to enclose the loop calculations by a begin/end block.

It should be:

```
for n := 0 to n_max-1 do
begin
  r[n]:= cod/2 + h*n;
  R1[n] := (r[n]*(nip_dia)/2)/(r[n]+(nip_dia)/2);
  f[n] := nip*((r[n]-r[0])/r[n]);
  h0[n] :=4*viscosity*velocity*(1/(60*(R1[n]/f[n])));
end;
```

See documentation [For Statements](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE4/en/Declarations_and_Statements#For_Statements).